# Convert function opencv to opencvsharp

Tags: c#, opencv

I have this issues, I want use to function cv::initUndistortRectifyMap on C# and I'm using Opencvsharp - Cv2.InitUndistortRectifyMap.The problem is parameters "inputarray r" not true. Somebody have example for this issues.

This is C++ code :

```cpp
cv::initUndistortRectifyMap(mt, mtdist,cv::Mat(), cv::getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(mt, mtdist, imageSize, 1, imageSize, 0), imageSize, CV_16SC2, map1, map2);
```

This is C# code:

```cs
Cv2.InitUndistortRectifyMap(mt, mtdist,map(wrong), Cv2.GetOptimalNewCameraMatrix(mt, mtdist, src.Size(), 1, src.Size(), out rect, false), src.Size(), MatType.CV_16SC2, map1, map2);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `r` parameter is really an optional one. It's for additional stereo transformation.

You can give it an empty Mat or UMat and according to the documentation it will use the identity matrix instead, doing no additional transformation.

OpenCV documentation:
https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga7dfb72c9cf9780a347fbe3d1c47e5d5a

Code Example:

```
Cv2.InitUndistortRectifyMap(
                CameraMatrix,
                DistortionMatrix,
                tokenTracker.NewUMat(),
                newCameraMatrix,
                newImageSize,
                MatType.CV_32F,
                map1,
                map2);
```

Where `tokenTracker.NewUMat()` is creating a new managed UMat via `ResourcesTracker tokenTracker`.

Using your code:

```
Cv2.InitUndistortRectifyMap(
                mt,
                mtdist,
                new Mat(),
                Cv2.GetOptimalNewCameraMatrix(
                    mt,
                    mtdist,
                    src.Size(),
                    1,
                    src.Size(),
                    out rect,
                    false),
                src.Size(),
                MatType.CV_16SC2,
                map1,
                map2);
```

Note: I did not used a `ResourceTracker` in this example. So the `new Mat()` has unmanaged memory.